# Bootstrapping each column in a DF and replacing the column values with the bootstrap samples

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm looking to bootstrap 1000 times each column in a dataframe and then replace the few values in each column with the 1000 bootstrapped samples, so as to each column now has 1000 rows. Does anyone have any idea how could I code that? So that from having a data frame like the one on top I end up with a data frame like the one in the bottom with all 1000 sampled values. Thank you!

| Col 1. | Col 2. |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | 3. |
| 4. | 5. |
| 7. | 1. |
| 1. | 9. |

| Col 1. | Col 2. |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | 3. |
| 4. | 5. |
| 1. | 5. |
| 7. | 1. |
| 1. | 9. |
| 1. | 1. |
| 1. | 5. |
| 7. | 1. |
| ...n=1000 | ...n=1000 |

Comment: Please provide an explicit, minimal, reproducible example

Comment: Just did, hopefully this helps.

Comment: so you want to have 1000 random samples of Col1 and Col2 without necessarily keeping the original matches?

Comment: Exactly so then I can just sample with replacement each x amount of columns  independently and replace the columns values with the bootstrapped samples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to randomly sample Col1 and Col2 independently, with replacement:

```
n = 1000

import numpy as np

out = (df[['Col 1.']]
       .sample(n=n, replace=True, ignore_index=True)
       .assign(**{'Col 2.': np.random.choice(df['Col 2.'], size=n, replace=True)})
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
     Col 1.  Col 2.
0       7.0     1.0
1       1.0     5.0
2       1.0     9.0
3       1.0     1.0
4       7.0     9.0
..      ...     ...
995     1.0     5.0
996     4.0     9.0
997     4.0     9.0
998     1.0     1.0
999     4.0     9.0

[1000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you so much. How would you implement this for a larger amount of columns?